# Unable to follow Step 3 of Configuring MSAL for iOS

Tags: ios, azure-ad-msal

I am trying to follow instruction for configuring MSAL in this website: 
https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-objc

I am on step #3 of Configuring MSAL, but I am running on roadblocks.

first issue: 
On my AppDelegate.m file created by React-Native, there is already a function named application

```
/**
 * Copyright (c) Facebook, Inc. and its affiliates.
 *
 * This source code is licensed under the MIT license found in the
 * LICENSE file in the root directory of this source tree.
 */

#import "AppDelegate.h"

#import <React/RCTBridge.h>
#import <React/RCTBundleURLProvider.h>
#import <React/RCTRootView.h>

@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
  RCTBridge *bridge = [[RCTBridge alloc] initWithDelegate:self launchOptions:launchOptions];
  RCTRootView *rootView = [[RCTRootView alloc] initWithBridge:bridge
                                                   moduleName:@"pat"
                                            initialProperties:nil];

  rootView.backgroundColor = [[UIColor alloc] initWithRed:1.0f green:1.0f blue:1.0f alpha:1];

  self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
  UIViewController *rootViewController = [UIViewController new];
  rootViewController.view = rootView;
  self.window.rootViewController = rootViewController;
  [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
  return YES;
}

- (NSURL *)sourceURLForBridge:(RCTBridge *)bridge
{
#if DEBUG
  return [[RCTBundleURLProvider sharedSettings] jsBundleURLForBundleRoot:@"index" fallbackResource:nil];
#else
  return [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"main" withExtension:@"jsbundle"];
#endif
}

@end
```

where would I put the code in the instruction?

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)app
            openURL:(NSURL *)url
            options:(NSDictionary<UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey,id> *)options
{
    return [MSALPublicClientApplication handleMSALResponse:url 
                                         sourceApplication:options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsSourceApplicationKey]];
}
```

If I modify the original application method, another error is popping up on this line

```
return [MSALPublicClientApplication handleMSALResponse:url 
                                     sourceApplication:options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsSourceApplicationKey]];
```

as the method signature only has 1 argument for this method and not two, and if I remove the second argument to build the program, my app will not start at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function you need to add is a different function to `didFinishLaunching`.  Objective C considers the entire method signature, not just the first parameter. The function isn't called `application`, it is called `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` while the new method you need to add is `application:openURL:options:`.

You can just add the Microsoft supplied function to your `AppDelegate.m` file

Comment: Thanks for the answer, luckily I was able to resolve the issue by looking at the sample codes provided on the repository: https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-objc . Your right, I can add that method as it is written in the guide without issues. For my second question I was able to resolve it by updating my MSAL using pod update. Apparently I had an older version of the function, when it was updated to 1.0.7, the code worked.